# Is it possible to log out of 'mail' on the iPad?

Tags: ipad, email

I set up my email into the iPad 'Mail' app, and I cannot find how you log out to prevent another user from opening and reading my mail.

Is it possible to log out of 'mail' on the iPad?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I know, this is not possible. iPad is not made to be a multi-user device. I am in a similar situation myself as I share the iPad with my wife but haven't yet fixed it. Some alternatives:

1. Set a different account as default account in Settings > Mail, Contacts, Calendars. It could even be a dummy account. At least it means email will not be sent accidentally from your address.
2. In Settings > Mail, Contacts, Calendars > [Your email account], you can turn off Mail temporarily. It does not provide any security though, anyone can just turn it on again.
3. If you want to guarantee security, you need to use something like Gmail in Safari and login and logout every time.

Comment: I'm considering the same thing actually.. I'd actually like to write an applescript like i have for my desktop to disable my mail while I'm at work because everytime i get an email my MBP, iPhone and iPad all go off and it's annoying haha

Answer (score 3):

You can turn a mail account on/off as explained by RipperDoc (Settings -> Mail,Contacts,Calendars).

On the iPhone, you can also turn off the ability to change the Mail settings; which requires a passcode.  Settings -> General -> Restrictions -> Allow Changes (Accounts)

It's a bit of a hassle; but, by turning off the mail account, and then disallowing changes to the account settings, you can prevent the mail from being accessed.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Settings → Mail, Contacts & Calendars, then go to your email settings and erase your password. Enter a fake password and save it. Ignore the warnings and push done. You will be signed out until you go back and enter the correct password.

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Settings > Mail, contacts, calendars** and in the list of accounts,  tap the On/Off button to turn off Outlook.

Answer (score -1):

Delete the account from the device as advised, and use it in Safari.

Answer (score -1):

For an iPad, go into settings under Mail, Contacts, Calender, you will have the option to delete the account.

Comment: This doesn't exactly answer the question. The question was how to prevent other users from accessing email by logging out, not by deleting the account.

Answer (score -2):

It is possible. You have to go to `Settings > Mail, Contacts, Calendars` and delete the profile from mail. This will delete the account from your device only, it will *not* delete your stuff stored in iCloud itself.

Answer (score -3):

As a drastic measure you could remove the account by going to Settings -> Mail/Contacts/Calendars and deleting it there.

Comment: I think deleting the account would be a bit drastic measure to just log out.

Comment: Well, it's the only way to do it.

Answer (score -3):

Go to settings go to mail (it will say mail contacts calendars) once your in scroll to the bitten it will say delet account

Answer (score -3):

Go into settings mail and delete account

Answer (score -4):

just go to setting, click mail and put mail off.. thats all finish, want to access again mail on.

Comment: This doesn't prevent somebody else from turning it on themselves.

Answer (score -4):

Go to Settings, Reset App, and Reset. The next time you open the app, it will ask you for the user and password.

Comment: Sorry, where is this "Reset App" option in Settings in iOS?

Answer (score -5):

Go to settings then select mail go to hotmail or whatever you use and delete the account from your device you can always log back on when you want to

Answer (score -6):

Go to settings, click mail, click the first button ( the one thats at the top ) , click delete account andd PROBLEM SOLVED!

Comment: you solution is to delete the account?